# Resistor heating even at low power dissipation

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, circuit-design, current-source

I am designing a constant current source to power up a 10 W RGB LED (please see the circuit attached). Each R, G, and B consume around 400 mA maximum. I am designing my circuit at 330 mA. I have used 12 ohm (3 x 4 ohm, I don't have access to 12 ohm single resistor right now) shunt resistance. I am getting the expected current at 4 V drop across the resistors and thus 333 mA current. The power dissipation is given by the formula,

Power dissipation = I * I * R.

From the above calculation, the maximum power dissipation across all 3 resistors should be 1.33 W. I am using 3 W (each) resistors and the resistors start heating up after a few seconds. I have even used 5 W resistors, the same result. I am not able to understand what is the cause of resistors heating.

LED[image]

Comment: Many resistors are rated at scolding hot temperatures, so even if you run it at 1/10 of the power, they may become uncomfortable hot to touch.

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and **Save and Insert** on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Your schematic has an error that causes the output of the TL081 to go as high as it can with no regulation. The error is that it has no negative power supply voltage. The negative power supply voltage must be at least 4V more negative than the input voltages (TL081 has Opamp Phase Inversion problem).

Comment: Is your LED DC supply *really* +6V? Not enough. Base voltage of the transistor must rise to over +4.6, and a Blue or green LED will consume about 3V more. It is good to limit power dissipation in Q1 by using a large-value current-sense resistor (12 ohm) since power resistors can likely run hotter than transistors. But at max current, transistor collector voltage must be greater (or equal to) its base voltage. If you intend to adjust current to zero, you'll need a -ve supply on that opamp of at least -1.5V

Comment: @glen_geek The LED forward drop voltage is 6V. I have applied voltage up to 12V but facing the same issue. The transistor doesn't get hot as it has 1A Ic (max) so I am well in the range.

Comment: @Noman To keep wasted dissipation down, it's better that you use a different circuit topology combined with a different power supply rail (for example, 8 or 9 V instead of 12 V.) Are you able to consider something like that? I ask because if your LED does require 6 V (usually, it's not so simple as that, but leaving that fact for another discussion for now) and if you must use a 12 V rail, then a linear system must dissipate away the same power as your LED. Which often isn't the better choice when talking on the order of 10 W.

Comment: Note that a buck converter can maintain an almost-constant current without wasting as much power.

Answer (score 5):

You need to read the datasheet to understand what the temperature rise relative to ambient will be at a particular power.

The power rating doesn't mean it will stay close to room temperature at that power. Effectively it will reach its safe operating temperature subject to certain ambient conditions and airflow at that power.

[image]

*Figure 1. Derating for [a random 5 W resistor](https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/res_50.pdf?r=false).*

Here we see that the resistor is unable to dissipate any power if the ambient temperature is 350°C. This suggests to me that the core of the resistor cannot exceed this temperature. I suspect, therefore, that at 25°C ambient and 100% power that the core will reach the same temperature and the resistor will be very, very hot. At 50% power I would expect the temperature to rise by (350 - T<sub>amb</sub>) × 0.5. You could calculate the expected temperature rise for this resistor as \$ \frac {350 - 25} 5 = 65 K/W \$. Interestingly that resistor is rated at only 1000 hours with a duty cycle of 1.5 hours ON / 0.5 hours OFF.

Edit your question with a link to the datasheet of your resistors if you can't figure it out and someone will help.

Comment: I purchased it from AliExpress, don't have access to its specific datasheet. The resistor size is same as shown in photo on website https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32830172065.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.7a31598bbXABy5&algo_pvid=b87487f4-8e7b-4513-a83e-b3d6772ecd0a&algo_exp_id=b87487f4-8e7b-4513-a83e-b3d6772ecd0a-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265031373223%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21PKR%21%21945.54%21945.54%21%21%21%21%402101d4a716611067672556751e67a0%2165031373223%21sea&gatewayAdapt=glo2tur

Comment: I have access to the same 5W resistor that you used for the demonstration. It starts heating up when I exceed 1W across it.

Comment: "*It starts heating up when I exceed 1W across it.*" Um, what did you expect? Did you calculate the expected temperature rise? What temperature rise did you get?

Answer (score 4):

The power rating of the resistors means that it is safe for the resistor to dissipate 3 W  (or 5 W). Of course the size of the resistor does not influence the actual power dissipation, which in any case is 1.3 W.

1.3 W in a small package is actually significant, and you will notice how they run quite hot quite quickly. The actual steady state temperature depends on the thermal conductivity from resistor to the ambient air.

Answer (score 3):

There are two separate things. First thing, how much power will the resistor dissipate. This is based on I * I * R as you say. Changing from a 3 W resistor to a 5 W resistor will not change that.

The second thing is, how hot will the resistor get in the process? This is controlled by how large the resistor is physically. There is no magic way for a resistor to dissipate 1.5 Watts without warming up. A massive resistor might be able to dissipate 1.5 Watts without much heating. But any practical sized resistor is going to warm up.

For a given dissipation, the smaller the resistor, the hotter it will have to get. The larger the resistor, the cooler it will remain. Any time dissipation gets up near 1 Watt on a circuit board you need to think about heat sinks and so-on. The resistor may be able to dissipate 1 Watt, but that is enough heat to warm up the entire circuit board or enclosure that the circuit board resides in.

If your circuit dissipates 5 Watts or 10 Watts, then it is likely that thermal design will be just as important or even more important than electrical design.

Comment: I purchased the resistor from AliExpress and here is the link. I have the same size resistor shown in photo. https://tr.aliexpress.com/item/32830172065.html?spm=a2g0o.search0304.0.0.7a31598bbXABy5&algo_pvid=b87487f4-8e7b-4513-a83e-b3d6772ecd0a&algo_exp_id=b87487f4-8e7b-4513-a83e-b3d6772ecd0a-2&pdp_ext_f=%7B%22sku_id%22%3A%2265031373223%22%7D&pdp_npi=2%40dis%21PKR%21%21945.54%21945.54%21%21%21%21%402101d4a716611067672556751e67a0%2165031373223%21sea&gatewayAdapt=glo2tur

Comment: In that photo, there is nothing for scale, so I am not sure how big those resistors are. But it also seems there are no detailed specifications. The basic physical fact is that in order for a SMALL PART to dissipate 1.5 W, it must get very, very hot. If it is made from heat resistant material, maybe that is OK for it to get hot. But you cannot expect a small part to dissipate 1.5 W without getting hot because it is impossible (physically). Some surface mount resistors are designed to transfer heat to the PCB, and sometimes that might be easier to deal with.

Comment: Please check this. https://www.ohmite.com/assets/docs/res_50.pdf?r=false. I have access to the same resistor (5W) and tested that as well. It remains a little warm up till 1W consumption and then starts heating up as I reach my target of 1.33W consumption.

Comment: That resistor should be OK dissipating 1.33 W, but in the long run, if your PCB is inside an enclosure, the entire enclosure will heat up quite a bit.